# Communication between two GraphQL api in java

Tags: graphql-java

I have a service developed using GraphQL kickstarter and spring Boot starter,
Now I want to  consume the data from graphql api using spring boot.Kindly provide me any suggestion to consume the graphQL api using spring boot.

Below is the sample request

query getBookdetail($isbnCode:String!){
getBookdetails(isbnCode:$isbnCode){
title
isbn
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Consuming the graphql API can be done using below steps

Generate the schema file from your graghQL API ,it will give you the schema.json data
example :http://localhost:8080/graphql/schema.json

create the folder src/main/graphql in your project and place your schema.json file in the folder
Create a file with .graphql in the src/main/graphql in your project and copy the above the query

```
query getBook($isbn:String!){
    book1:getBook(isbn:$isbn){
     title
    } 
}
```

Add the below dependency to your pom.xml file

```
dependency>
       <groupId>com.apollographql.apollo</groupId>
       <artifactId>apollo-runtime</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.sparow199</groupId>
    <artifactId>apollo-client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                    <rootPackageName>com.example.graphqlAPI</rootPackageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

RUN the below command to generate the java file  mvn clean generate-sources
The generated file will be available in the target folder

Copy the generated java files to your project folder

On completing the above steps you can consume using the apollo client

```
package com.example.graphqlAPI.Controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloCall.Callback;
import com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloClient;
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response;
import com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloException;
import com.example.graphqlAPI.GetBookQuery;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApolloClientController {
    

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;

     private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApolloClientController.class);
     
        @GetMapping("/prod") 
  public Map<String,Object> processApi(@RequestParam (required = false) String isbn ){
        
        
            Map<String,Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        OkHttpClient okHTTPCLIENT = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        
        ApolloClient client = ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/graphql")
                .okHttpClient(okHTTPCLIENT).build();

        CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
        
        client.query(GetBookQuery.builder().isbn(isbn).build()).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                LOGGER.info("Res: {}", response.getData());
                hm.put("Response", response.getData());
                lock.countDown();
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ApolloException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 LOGGER.info("Err: {}", e);
                lock.countDown();
                hm.put("Error", "Error while fetchiing the data");
            }
        
        });
        try {
            lock.await(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hm;
    }

}
```